# How can I optimize this tailored Copy-on-Write POD array on linux?

Tags: linux, mmap

I'm trying to implement a tailored Copy-on-Write POD array on linux. The main thread is the creator of this array which creates a SHARED mmap on a temporary memory file and only extends its size, no writes (in fact, do I need this creator at all?). Multiple worker threads are doing PRIVATE mmap over this array with its current size, and they do read/write operations. Each work thread is supposed to have a sparse array (95% untouched). So I'd like to know if there is an efficient way to tell if a memory page is untouched, i.e., all zeroed and the worker thread can bypass the page directly. Can it be achieve on userland?